# Rails Migrations - Modify rows based on condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations

I need to update a table data in database using RAILS migrations.

```
Sample:
Table: Table_A(Col_A(number), Col_B(varchar),...)
Query: UPDATE Table_A SET Col_B = "XXX" where Col_B = "YYY"
```

What would be the best way to do this using RAILS Migrations. I am not even sure if RAILS migrations is the way to go for updating data in database. Any explanation would be helpful.

Comment: I will refer to the 2nd answer on this previous question about why is bad to change data with migrations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849897/can-rails-migrations-be-used-to-convert-data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's usually better to do these sorts of big data updates in a rake task. I usually write them so they have two versions: rake change_lots_of_data:report and rake change_lots_of_data:update. The 'report' version just executes the where clause and spits out a list of what would be changed. The 'update' version uses the very same where clause but makes the changes.

Some advantages of doing it this way are:

- Migrations are saved for changing the database structure
- You can run the 'report' version as often as you want to make sure the right records are going to be updated.
- It's easier to unit test the class called by the rake task.
- If you ever need to apply the same criteria to make the change again, you can just run the rake task again. It's possible but trickier to do that with migrations.

Comment: Wholeheartedly agree here.  Big data-updates are best left to rake tasks.  I've had some headaches trying to do this kind of thing in a migration that's followed by other migrations that alter the DB structure ever-so-slightly making the consecutive runs of migrations fail explosively.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer to do any database data changes in a rake task so that's it's

1. Obvious
2. Repeatable
3. Won't later be executed via `rake db:migrate`

The code:

```
namespace :update do
  desc "Update table A to set Col_B to YYY"
    task :table_a => :environment do
      TableA.where(Col_B: "YYY").update_all(Col_B: "XXX")
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can `rake update:table_a` to execute the update.

Comment: I fixed it for you. Cheers. PS: Seems like Stackoverflow can't handle code right after an ordered list, so there needs to be some text in between.

Answer (score 4):

This should be done in a rake task...

```
namespace :onetime do
  task :update_my_data => :environment do
    TableA.where(Col_B: "YYY").update_all(Col_B: "XXX")
  end
end
```

Then after you deploy:

`rake onetime:update_my_data`

At my company we delete the contents of the onetime namespace rake task after it's been run in production.  Just a convention for us I guess.

More details about the `update_all` method:  http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all

Comment: You are wrong. There is no mention of `Model` for table. And it is bad to use `Model` in migration.

Comment: Isn't that why I said "if your tables have a model"???  How do we know his table doesn't have a model?  I would argue it's bad to do any kind of mass-update in a migration.  Just make a rake task.

Comment: If the table does have a model associated with it, which is better, using execute or using the above mentioned way.

Comment: Still using `execute` is better in my view. Because using model is dangerous.

Comment: I would say my version in a rake task, execute version in a migration.  Personally I'd prefer the rake task...

Comment: If you want to use rake task I don't have problem with this method. But still I prefer writing seeds.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
 class YourMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def up    
     execute('UPDATE Table_A SET Col_B = "XXX" where Col_B = "YYY"')
   end

   def down
   end
 end
```

Or:

```
 class YourMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def up   
     update('UPDATE Table_A SET Col_B = "XXX" where Col_B = "YYY"')
   end

   def down
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("update Table_A set Col_B = 'XXX'  where Col_B = 'YYY')
```