# Best practice for running a data-fix / manipulation script in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails application hosted on heroku and want to `strip!` data from a specific text column. I was wondering what the most "rails" way to do this is. The model has been changed so that data are normalised when created or updated, but I want to apply this change to what is already there.

My situation is similar but not the same as: [Can Rails Migrations be used to convert data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849897/can-rails-migrations-be-used-to-convert-data/863892#863892)

I am interested on a rails-based approach and not a SQL script, which would be easy to replicate there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either a migration or (I would prefer) a rake task.

The benefit of the migration is that it would run just the once - and you should be able to write a roll-back 'down' script too.

The benefit of the rake task is it's separated from your dB scripts (as manipulating data *is* a different type of task).

Comment: Decided to go for rake task. I was not aware that it could be run within the environment.